# How to plotting python seaborn plots one by one inside a for cycle?

Tags: python, seaborn

```py
import seaborn as sns
for scf in scaffolds_to_test:
    filter_df1 = filter_df.loc[filter_df['sseqid'] == scf]
    start_end = list(zip(list(filter_df1.sstart),list(filter_df1.send)))
    test_list1 = list(map(lambda t: (int(t[0]/10),int(t[1]/10)), sorted(start_end)))
    my_dict1 = dict()
    for t in test_list1:
        if t[0] > t[1]:
            t = (t[1],t[0])
        for f in range(t[0],t[1]+1):
            if f in my_dict1:
                my_dict1[f] = my_dict1[f] + 1
            else:
                my_dict1[f] = 1
    #display(sseqid)
    sseqid = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict1, orient='index')
    sseqid = sseqid.reset_index()
    sseqid.columns=["pos","score"]
    sns.scatterplot(data=sseqid, x="pos", y="score")
```

the last line is the imporant one. Im trying to run that inside the for cycle and its combining all plots into one.

I would like one clearly separate graph per each time I'm calling the .scatterplot(), or I would like to know how to do it another way.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `plt.show()` after the scatterplot inside the loop? Remember to import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Answer (score 1):

you can sue subplot in module suplotlib.plt

but, you must know the numer of plot in order to make the best config (lines/columns)

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n_plots=len(scaffolds_to_test)
c_plots=1
for scf in scaffolds_to_test:
    filter_df1 = filter_df.loc[filter_df['sseqid'] == scf]
    start_end = list(zip(list(filter_df1.sstart),list(filter_df1.send)))
    test_list1 = list(map(lambda t: (int(t[0]/10),int(t[1]/10)), sorted(start_end)))
    my_dict1 = dict()
    for t in test_list1:
        if t[0] > t[1]:
            t = (t[1],t[0])
        for f in range(t[0],t[1]+1):
            if f in my_dict1:
                my_dict1[f] = my_dict1[f] + 1
            else:
                my_dict1[f] = 1
    #display(sseqid)
    sseqid = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict1, orient='index')
    sseqid = sseqid.reset_index()
    sseqid.columns=["pos","score"]
    ax = plt.subplot(1,n_plots,c_plots)
    sns.scatterplot(data=sseqid, x="pos", y="score",ax=ax)
    c_plots+=1
```

Comment: it kind of works, but it displays all of the graphs in the same inline. Have you tried?

Comment: YES i test it but not with sns, because i dont have the data, the subplot is working well, did you tested this code?!